# Bash Delete doublons within array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a file containing a several number of fields. I am trying to delete doublons (ex: two same attributes with a different date.) within a same field. For example from this :

```
Andro   manual  gene    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc;Name=truc;modified=13-09-1993;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
Andro   manual  mRNA    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc-mRNA;Name=truc-mRNA;modified=13-09-1993;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
```

We can see modified=13-09-1993 and modified=13-09-1997 are doublons. So I want to obtain this :

```
Andro   manual  gene    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc;Name=truc;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
Andro   manual  mRNA    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc-mRNA;Name=truc-mRNA;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
```

I want to keep the latest occurence of particular attribute and deleting the oldest one. They will only have at maximum twice the same attribute in a same row.

I've tried this code (which is now working):

```
INPUT=$1
ID=$2
ALL_FEATURES=()
CONTIG_FEATURES=$(grep $ID $INPUT)
while read LINE; do
    FEATURES=$(echo -e "$LINE" | cut -f 9)
    #For each line, store all attributes from every line in an array
    IFS=';' read -r -a ARRAY <<< "$FEATURES"
    #Once the array is created, loop in array to look for doublons
    for INDEX in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        ELEMENT=${ARRAY[INDEX]}
        #If we are not at the end of the array, compare actual element and next element     
        ACTUAL=$ELEMENT
        for INDEX2 in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
        do
            NEXT="${ARRAY[INDEX2]}"
            ATTRIBUTE1=$(echo -e "$ACTUAL" | cut -d'=' -f1)
            ATTRIBUTE2=$(echo -e "$NEXT" | cut -d'=' -f1)
            echo "Comparing element number $INDEX ($ATTRIBUTE1) with element number $INDEX2 ($ATTRIBUTE2) ..."
            if [[ $ATTRIBUTE1 = $ATTRIBUTE2 ]] && [[ $INDEX -ne $INDEX2 ]]
            then
                echo "Deleting features..."
                #Delete actual element, because next element will be more recent
                NEW=()
                for VAL in "${ARRAY[@]}"
                do
                        [[ $VAL != "${ARRAY[INDEX]}" ]] && NEW+=($VAL)
                done
                ARRAY=("${NEW[@]}")
                unset NEW
            fi
        done

    done    
    #Rewriting array into string separated by ;
    FEATURES2=$( IFS=$';'; echo "${ARRAY[*]}" )
    sed -i "s/$FEATURES/$FEATURES2/g" $INPUT



done < <(echo -e "$CONTIG_FEATURES")
```

I need advices because I think my array approache may not be a clever one, but I want a bash solution in any case. If anyone has some bash adives/shortcuts, any suggestions will be appreciated to improve my bash understanding.

I'm sorry if I forgot any details, thanks for your help.

Roxane

Comment: I think you get lost in the sed statement

Comment: For your own sake, pick a more capable language to write this script.

Comment: define your *doublons*

Comment: Okay, I added a defintion of what I consider as a doublon.
So, I don't think the sed is the problem here. My problem come from the reorganisation of array : 
 [[ $VAL != "${ARRAY[INDEX]}" ]] && NEW+=($VAL)

Because $FEAUTURES2 do not contains what I expected. In the example above, ID does not have a doublons but is deleted anyway. I can't understand why.

Maybe you are right and I should use an other language, but the rest of my pipeline is written in bash, so I saw it more like a challenge to train myself dealing with bash array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
{
    n=split($NF,a,";")              # split the last field by ;
    for(i=n;i>=1;i--) {             # iterate them backwards to keep the last "doublon"
        split(a[i],b,"=")           # split key=value at = 
        if(b[1] in c==0) {          # if key not in c hash
            d=a[i] (d==""?"":";") d # append key=value to d with ;
            c[b[1]]                 # hash key into c
        }
    } 
    $NF=d                           # set d to last field
    delete c                        # clear c for next record
    d=""                            # deetoo
}
1                                   # output
' file
Andro manual gene 1 100 . + . ID=truc;Name=truc;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
Andro manual mRNA 1 100 . + . ID=truc-mRNA;Name=truc-mRNA;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
```

Comment: Wow, that's really clever. awk is truly amazing. I don't think enough about it. I need to practive more. Thanks a lot for that solution ! That was exactly what I was looking for ! Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

Following awk could also help you in same.

```
awk -F';' '{
for(i=NF;i>0;i--){
  split($i, array,"=");
  if(++a[array[1]]>1){
   $i="\b"
}
};
delete a
}
1
' OFS=";"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Andro   manual  gene    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc;Name=truc;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
Andro   manual  mRNA    1   100 .   +   .   ID=truc-mRNA;Name=truc-mRNA;added=13-09-1993;modified=13-09-1997
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works as well, and it's even shorter :)

Comment: @Roxane, your welcome. Glad that it helped you, keep learning and keep sharing knowledge, cheers.